# How to update attribute value from object in a ListView

Tags: c#

I have two files. One file with a class called *Wood*. I have created some objects with this class. These Objects include the attribute *WoodType* and a few others. I filled the objects into an array called *woodObjects*. The second file is a Form where I have a **ListView**.

So my goal was, to add all objects with their attributes to the ListView. I did it like that:

```
String[] row = { (listView1.Items.Count + 1).ToString(), WoodType, condition, isDry};
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Success.

Now I have to update the attribute *WoodType* of one object in the ListView. I created a button "change Type" for that. I thought of the user clicking the row where the object ist he wants to change, and then clicking the button "change Type" to change *WoodType* it. 
To realize this, I wanted to take the index of the row, and than changing the value of "WoodType" with its **set Accessor** with something like the following:

```
woodObjects[indexOfRowFromListView].WoodType = "Oak Wood";
```

Yes, I know, this would never work like that. So my questions are: How can I select the correct index and how do I change the value of the attribute?

*I also thought of deleting the objects, but saving its values so I can create a new objects with the same values except *WoodType*.
I appreciate every help!

Comment: @MehdiDehghani The problem is, that I dont know how to get the correct index. After i got the index, i have to know, how to change the value of the attribute. I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: ListView should have a property called SelectedIndex.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Yes I do. I can also get the row with Ecordero 's solution. The main problem really is, how I can change the value of the attribute.

Comment: @welrocken Thanks. And how can I change the value of the attribute now when i have the index?

Comment: woodObjects[listView.SelectedIndex].WoodType = "New Value";

Comment: @welrocken That wouldn't work. The listView index isn't the same as the array index.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani the attribute "WoodType". I want to change the value of it.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Thank you. I could already solve my problem :)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest solution to your problem would involve writing a new ListViewItem implementation. Something like this:

```
public class WoodObjectListItem : System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
{
    public Wood WoodObject { get; }

    public WoodObjectListItem(int rowNumber, Wood woodObject) 
        : base(new string[] { rowNumber.ToString(), woodObject.WoodType, woodObject.Condition, woodObject.IsDry })
    {
        WoodObject = woodObject;
    }

    public void ChangeType()
    {
        WoodObject.WoodType = "Oak Wood";
    }
}
```

Then you could add your woodObjects to the list view like:

```
listView1.Items.Add(new WoodObjectListItem(listView1.Items.Count + 1, woodObject));
```

And when the button is clicked you could do:

```
if (listView1.SelectedItem is WoodObjectListItem woodObjectListItem)
    woodObjectListItem.ChangeType();
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much. Solved my problem!